# Partition By List and Range at the same time - Multiple Partitions MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, partitioning, database-partitioning

Is that possible in MySQL to use List and Range partitions together.
Let say

1. I have different categories and i want to put each category in "List Partition"
2. Now each category I want to create "Range partition" due to huge amount of data daily for each category

Further, I don't want to make separate tables physically for each category

Example Query

```
Select * FROM table1 WHERE category_id = 1 AND dt BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'
```

If We have let say thousand of categories and each day there are million of records against each category on daily basis. If we do multiple Partitions on category plus monthly(just suppose can be weekly if required) basis against each category and  then we can get great benefit as for fetching specific category and its data in datetime range we look only in that partition better than looking in one partition containing Billion of rows for every category

Comment: I have yet to see a use for `SUBPARTITIONs`.  Just because there is a "huge" amount of data does not mean that partitioning, of any kind, will help any.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (even without partitions), some queries, and explain why you think partitioning is a good idea.

Comment: And elaborate on why you can't normalize.  It is important for keeping the table 'smaller'.  But do not normalize "continuous" values, such as dates or floats.

Comment: @RickJames If you have let say thousand of categories and each day there are million of records against each category. If you do Sub-Partitions  on category plus monthly(just suppose can be weekly if required) basis against each category and you write queries according to your partitions then we can get great benefit as for fetching specific category and its data in datetime range we look only in that partition better than using only single range partition for all range

Comment: @RickJames edited question for Normalization part as i have already normalize table Thanks for pointing it out. Gracious

Comment: @RickJames Read your article http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
Nicely written but why you said Sub-Partition is Useless. Please Elaborate and oblige

Comment: In _most_ cases, drilling down a multi-column index is as fast or faster than first picking the partition (and subpartition), then drilling down the index in that [sub]partition to finally find the desired row.

Comment: That particular `SELECT` works perfectly well without partitioning, but with this composite index: `INDEX(category_id, dt)` -- with the columns in that order.

Comment: I don't really have a "good" argument against `SUBPARTITIONs` -- other that to (1) reiterate the arguments I use against `PARTITIONs`, and (2) observe that I have yet to find any use for them.  If you have one, please present the specific use case, including `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with subpartitions and the `SELECT` that benefits.  I may have to "eat my words".  In which case, I will update that document and reference you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer myself the solution to this is "Composite Partitioning" or also known as "Sub-Partitioning"

[Here are details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html)

Sub-Partitioning is also supported by other DBMS too